# How to fix "Failed to package application" with "android/res" errors?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have no idea what started causing this issue, but all of a sudden I cannot build for Android and I am getting this error stack in my console. I've found lots of resources on how to fix this for pure Android, but **how do I fix this in a Appcelerator project?**

I'm currently building with version 3.5.1 of the Titanium SDK.

```
[INFO]  Packaging application: /Users/owen/Library/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt "package" "-f" "-m" "-J" "/Users/owen/Documents/AppC/mobilevodapp/build/android/gen" "-M" "/Users/owen/Documents/AppC/mobilevodapp/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml" "-A" "/Users/owen/Documents/AppC/mobilevodapp/build/android/bin/assets" "-S" "/Users/owen/Documents/AppC/mobilevodapp/build/android/res" "-I" "/Users/owen/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-19/android.jar" "-F" "/Users/owen/Documents/AppC/mobilevodapp/build/android/bin/app.ap_" "--auto-add-overlay" "--extra-packages" "ti.modules.titanium.ui:android.support.v7.appcompat:com.brightcove.player" "-S" "/var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-7o4qib/res" "-S" "/var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res"
[ERROR] Failed to package application:
[ERROR]   
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_clear_normal.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_clear_normal.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /var/folders/hr/xzz1tf1568777t8vskffwcvw0000gn/T/11621-1324-1wler2t/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
[ERROR] /Users/owen/Documents/AppC/mobilevodapp/build/android/res/drawable-mdpi/player_knob_59d23724f1.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /Users/owen/Documents/AppC/mobilevodapp/build/android/res/drawable-hdpi/player_knob_59d23724f1.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /Users/owen/Documents/AppC/mobilevodapp/build/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/player_knob_59d23724f1.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /Users/owen/Documents/AppC/mobilevodapp/build/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/player_knob_59d23724f1.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] /Users/owen/Documents/AppC/mobilevodapp/build/android/res/layout/default_media_controller.xml:39: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'splitTrack' in package 'android'
[ERROR]   
[ERROR] /Users/owen/Documents/AppC/mobilevodapp/build/android/res/layout-w480dp/default_media_controller.xml:72: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'splitTrack' in package 'android'

2016-03-01T11:03:22.000Z | ERROR  | ti run exited with error code
```

Here are the Android specific settings in my TiApp.xml:

```
  <android 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest android:versionCode="01750300" android:versionName="3.0.0" package="uk.co.uktv.dave" 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="23" android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
      <application android:largeHeap="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.UKTV">
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiTranslucentActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
      </application>
    </manifest>
  </android>
```

Comment: Try run app using `TISDK5.2.0.GA`

Comment: Did you change anything since your last successful build? Did you change the SDK version in `tiapp.xml` or `ti sdk select`? Did you clean (`ti clean`) the project before the build to see if that helps?

Comment: I have only made normal code changes since my last build. I've kept the SDK version at 3.5.1 (unfortunately I can't upgrade right now). I have also tried `ti clean`, and deleted the build folder. Unfortunately I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen errors like this with custom themes. Have you made changes to the theme since the last successful build?

For example, when I have specified colors or graphics in the wrong file. For example in the themes_*.xml when it should be in styles_*.xml or vice-versa. I've also gotten them when I've specified non-existent android properties or assigned to the `android:prop` when it should be `prop`

From my working theme, I have a style like:

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Mytheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_myapp</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_myapp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

If I were to change it to the following, I'd expect to get errors like the ones you're seeing.

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Mytheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_myapp</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_myapp</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

(This is a totally made up fail-case and maybe that wouldn't actually throw the errors. But, I've struggled with errors like yours that were caused by assigning to the wrong attribute.)